# Working with an AWS API gateway with limited time

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I created a lambda function that makes a call to an api that accepts a json file. The json file can have about 25 email addresses that is required for processing. Two email addresses are processed in 17seconds. Our api gateway has a limitation of 29 seconds to run an api. The list of email addresses can be as high as 50.
How can I write this effectively so that I can process 2 email addresses in less than 20 seconds each? I am using python and AWS lambda function.

Comment: Does your lambda need to wait for the response from the other API that processes the JSON?

Comment: Yes I need the response to process error messages if any.

Comment: If the other API is taking too much time to process, then it's something that the other API needs to take care of processing emails efficiently. If it's your lambda logic that's taking too much time to process emails, I can't suggest anything without knowing your lambda logic. If you don't have to wait for the response, you could push the emails to SQS and do it asynchronously. You could hook up your SQS with Lambda and to SQS to send errors to your email or whatever. I'm not really sure of your use case here.